# Android | Non-stop transition form an animation to an animatorSet

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to make an combined animation where a view is first moved (TranslateAnimation) and then hidden/revealed (createCircularReveal Animator)([like here](http://slides.com/dmytrodanylyk/material-animation#/9/3)). Rigth now, I am accomplishing it by starting the animator after the animation with the onAnimationEnd callback. But the thing is, it does not start right away but is delayed for like half a second which makes it look less smooth.

Is this even the right aaproach to do this, or is there another way to create such an move + property animation?

Is there may be a way to adjust the onAnimationEnd callback so that it really start rigth away?

EDIT: here my final code:

```
...
        final Animator circularReveal = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(
                ....
        );
        circularReveal.setDuration(3500);
        circularReveal.setInterpolator(new AnimationUtils().loadInterpolator(YourWorkouts.this,
                android.R.interpolator.linear_out_slow_in));
        circularReveal.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationStart(animation);
                createNewWorkoutDialogCardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        final Animator circularHide = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(
                ...
        );
        circularHide.setDuration(600);
        circularHide.setInterpolator(new AnimationUtils().loadInterpolator(YourWorkouts.this,
                android.R.interpolator.linear_out_slow_in));
        circularHide.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                Log.v("YourWorkouts", "onAnimationEnd: set FAB INVISIBLE");
                createWorkoutFab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        final AnimatorSet animSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animSet.playTogether(circularHide,circularReveal);
        animSet.setStartDelay(300); // the animator waits only 0.3 seconds 

        Integer fabTranslationDistanceX = fabEndPositionX - (createNewWorkoutFABContainer.getLeft() + createNewWorkoutFABContainer.getWidth()/2);
        Integer fabTranslationDistanceY = fabEndPositionY - createWorkoutFab.getHeight()/2  - (createNewWorkoutFABContainer.getTop() + createNewWorkoutFABContainer.getHeight()/2);
        Log.v("YourWorkouts", "xDialogCenter" + fabTranslationDistanceX);
        TranslateAnimation moveFAB = new TranslateAnimation(0, fabTranslationDistanceX, 0, fabTranslationDistanceY);
        moveFAB.setDuration(500); // the translation takes 0.5 seconds
        moveFAB.setFillAfter(true);
        moveFAB.setInterpolator(new AnimationUtils().loadInterpolator(YourWorkouts.this,
                android.R.interpolator.fast_out_linear_in));

        animSet.start(); // start  animator for property animation
        createNewWorkoutFABContainer.startAnimation(moveFAB); // start animation to move view across the screen
```

Comment: being able to see your code could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this:

`anim1` will be the 1st animation, with a duration of 300 ms and `anim2` will start after 300 ms

```
TranslateAnimation anim1 = new TranslateAnimation();
Animator anim2 = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);

anim1.setDuration(300);

anim2.setDuration(300);
anim2.setStartOffset(300);
```

Comment: You cannot add an Animator to an AnimationSet, can you?

Comment: @SnafuBernd it gives no errors at compile time (I've tried it), but I'm not sure about what it does at run time.. just try it :)

Comment: @SnafuBernd ok my fault then. Anyway.. Please add your code to your question

Comment: OK funny, I accomplished it with animation delay, however I started Animator and Animation seperatlly in two code lines. And set the delay on 300 whereas the first animation takes 500, but now it really looks like the animator starts right after the animation. I mark this as the answer as the delay is the way to do it.